# MySQL photo like count. How to store & count millions of likes for photos?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am attempting to build an Instagram-like app and am not sure how to calculate the like count for each photo.

Option 1:

```
user Table
- user_id
- username
...

photo Table
- photo_id 
- user_id
- image_path
...

photo_like_relation Table
- like_id
- photo_id
- user_id 
...
```

So with this setup I will be able to retrieve the like count after counting the results from a a query like.

```
"SELECT * from photo_like_relation WHERE photo_id = x"
```

Option 2:

```
user Table
- user_id
- username
...

photo Table
- photo_id 
- user_id
- image_path
- like_count **
...

photo_like_relation Table
- like_id
- photo_id
- user_id 
...
```

With option 2 its self explanatory on how I will retrieve the like_count but I feel like this could get messy if there are ever any lapses in the system? Possibly the like_count total vs the COUNT() total of photo_like_relation may not match?

So which method is better? Or is there an even better method? Assume there are millions of photos/likes posted in the app.

I am attempting to recreate a popular page feature, like Instagram, which would basically grab the photos from the last X minutes with the most likes. I feel like this would be a huge burden on the system to loop through all of the photos posted from the last hour, and count how many records exist in the photo_like_relation table with the respective photo_id.

Thoughts? Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `COUNT()` function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM photo_like_relation
WHERE photo_id = x
```

Make sure you have an index on the `photo_id` column, and this should be very efficient.

Comment: Yup. You made need to optimise further once you have hundreds of thousands of users, but that's something you should probably come back and ask us about when it happens, rather than trying to optimise too early.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So the COUNT(*) is still quick if I am running it on 1000+ rows, with say, around 300+ likes on each photo?

Comment: If you have an index on the column in the `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` column, I believe the count information is in the index, so it's very fast.